# Most of a shapefile is not exporting to ArcGIS Online or Google Maps

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, point, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.6

I am having an issue where the vast majority of the shapefile and point data is not exporting from ArcMap. Its just in one particular area where the polylines show, the rest do not show and this is happening on both ArcGIS Online and on Google Maps, after using a KML conversion.

I tried recreating the shapefile, and when I do all the records export with all of the data. The polylines are not M-aware. When I share the map to ArcGIS Online, during the map analysis phase I get warnings that four of the shape and point files do not have a feature template. Could that be whats happening?

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/creating-new-features/best-practices-for-using-feature-templates.htm >?The layer has a visible scale range that is beyond the map's current scale.

Comment: Ok so do I need to recreate the data as a feature class using a template?

Comment: Just want to see if you can add some info to your question Is the issue wit exporting a layer in ArcMap or are you Sharing/Publishing a layer from ArcMap and the feature layer in ArcGIS Online is missing features?

Comment: Yes the issue is that when I share the layers from ArcMap into ArcGIS Online there are missing features. Ive been away from my desk for a while so I'm just now getting back to this.

Comment: Can you try using the repair geometry tool for the layer and use OGC validation option then try to republish with the repaired data?